# Two google play library in same project

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a old project that uses ActionBarSherlock library and old google play services project in workspace. Now, I need to add push notification to the project but, for this, I need compile com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0 then I have an exception "more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'. The issue is I need keep old google play project module because this project used old version of google maps with reference to getMap() within SherlockMapFragment.

How to I compile firebase and old google play project?. From old google play project only need maps component, could I compile one service from google play project?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try adding `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try this :

1. Remove old library of google play services, and keep the last 3 digits
2. Add firebase library

> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0

3. Add the needed part of the old library with the last 3 digits

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:X.Y.Z